# setting var as clicked button value and using var

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im setting the value of var x with the value of the clicked button. Then I want to use var x as the value in my jquery animation code.

```
var x = $('input').click(function() {
    $(this).val();
});

$("li").click(function() {
    $(this)
        .stop()
        .animate(
            {height:'150px'},
            {queue:false, duration:600, easing: x }
        );
});

$("li").mouseout(function() {  
    $(this)
        .stop()
        .animate(
            {height:'50px'},
            {queue:false, duration:600, easing: x });
});​
```

What am I doing wrong ?
Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/EnigmaMaster/z9dXA/7/

Comment: `x` will have the value `$('input')` after executing the first 3 lines, since `click` returns the same object as the one it was applied to

Comment: You have to define your var outside your function scopes. Take a look.

Answer (score 4):

### *[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3AA6s/2/)*

```
var x = '';    // define your var (make it re-usable inside functions)

$('input').click(function() {
   x = $(this).val();   // set your var'x' value for use.
});

$("li").click(function() {   
    $(this).stop().animate({height:150},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: x });
});
    
$("li").mouseout(function(){  
    $(this).stop().animate({height:50},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: x });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The click is asynchronous. Do it like this:

```
var x;
$('input').click(function() {
    x = $(this).val();
});
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z9dXA/8/

This will only work if the input is clicked before the li's are by the way, otherwise the x will have no value. Maybe provide a default value such as this:

```
var x = 'swing';
$('input').click(function() {
    x = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're currently setting `x` equal to the jQuery object returned by `$("input")`. The `.click()` method sets up a click handler that will be called *later* (when the click happens), so it doesn't return the value at the time of the click - it returns the same jQuery object as `$("input")` so that you can chain multiple jQuery methods together. That's why your `alert(y)` was showing `[object Object]`.

Try changing that first bit to this:

```
var x = "linear";  // give x a default value

$('input').click(function() {
    x = $(this).val();  // store the type of easing to be used
});
```

Then you don't actually need the `y` variable, you can just use `x` directly:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ height: '150px' }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 600,
        easing: x
    });
});

$("li").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ height: '50px'}, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 600,
        easing: x
    });
});​
```

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z9dXA/9/

Comment: You're welcome. Note that you're already making use of the "chaining" concept I mentioned when you say `$(this).stop().animate(...);`